# What does the charge counter in battery indicates?

Tags: battery, adb

I have used the `adb shell dumpsys battery` command on my phone. It delivers the following results (posted on the image). Most of the terms, I can understand but not the charge counter. What does it indicate and why does it decrease whenever I connect my phone to the USB cable? What is the significance of charge counter for battery?

I tried googling but cant find the answers.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I checked the Android source and the value shows your remaining battery capacity in microampere-hours.

```
BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER
Added in API level 21

public static final int BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER

Battery capacity in microampere-hours, as an integer.

Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
```

Source - [Developer.Android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER)

Comment: The temperature shows 350 is it in Kelvin or in other format. I have also another doubt lenovo vibe k5 note's output produces two presets and status. Does it mean it can hold two batteries?.

Comment: @BalaSubramanian the temperature is in tenth of a degree centrigrate. You divide it by 10 to get the celcius value. In your case it is 35 Degrees. The K5 doesn't seem to have 2 batteries, but maybe there's a difference in the way the system utlizies the battery cells. I don't have a clue about that.